# VB.net filtering access database

Tags: vb.net

I need help, I am making application for one medical practice.
I have one database where are all patients and one more where is all services (text), something like subdatabase. And when I make profile for patient, than I need to add some text to access DB. I know how to add new value to database but I don't know how to display only values for this patient. When I click Save I can see every value in this second database, I need to filter it with Patient ID.

[image: Screenshot with all patients]

[image: Screenshot of patient profile and DataGridView for his data]

Comment: If you search for "vb.net master detail datagridview" then you will find tutorials that deal with this.

Comment: The first question to answer is whether you want to load al the data at the outset and then filter in place or retrieve child data on demand.

Comment: When you say "Database", do you really mean "Table"?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Yes, I mean Table.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thank you, I will try. If I couldn’t find I will ask again.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I want to filter data for this patient when open his profile, and reload filtered datagridview after adding data to database from second form. Do you understand me?